# Bundle many files and load only requested one

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bundle

I'm new to bundle, and i have a project with lots of script files.

I'm using bundle and facing a problem with massive content by mean that i want to set bundle that contains about 20 files then later i want only to render one file or 3 files from this bundle not the whole bundle content (but also with bundle configuration like minification, ...).

I don't want to make lots of bundles

`bundles.add(new ScriptBundle(~/bundles/file1).include(file1.js));
 bundles.add(new ScriptBundle(~/bundles/file2).include(file2.js));
 bundles.add(new ScriptBundle(~/bundles/file3_4).include(file3.js)
                                                .include(file4.js));`

or use normal method to call script file 
`<script src='something.js'></script>`

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.Net Bundler isn't dynamic. The bundles are computed at application startup time, so you can't do any kind of selective rendering.

If you want to have some pages with only a few scripts, and some pages with more, then you would need to create a bundle for each page.

**Don't do that!**

If you are worried about including unnecessary scripts, then you have two options:

### 1) Include all scripts into a single bundle

With only 20 scripts this isn't necessarily a terrible option. It allows the browser to cache that file on first page load, and basically never request it again until it changes. This means that every other page will be very fast to load.

The downside is that anytime a single script changes, your entire bundle will be invalidated and need to be re-downloaded. Again, this is a one time cost.

### 2) Bundle your common scripts, and then include individual scripts on a per-page basis

This allows scripts that change less frequently (jQuery, underscore, angular, etc...) to be  optimized. At the same time, you can minimize the impact of scripts that might change in between releases for individual pages.

This means more requests per page, but those scripts should be smaller, and will also be cached just like everything else.

You could even create separate bundles per page, which should be simpler to maintain since  they will most likely only contain one or two scripts.

Comment: Thank you @Josh for your response. according to my status how can i render bundle in the same page after adding it to the bundle table?
I'm already rendering it from aspx file. using `Scripts.Render()` method. Is it working too from inside the page, or it will need to reload the page ?

Comment: @Kero - Well, if you have a master page you are best to add your common bundle there. You can render as many bundles as you need to by making multiple calls to `Render("~/bundles/mybundle")` with the appropriate path. Aside from that, you can just include individual `<script>` tags if you so desire.

Comment: Thank you @josh I think i will need to Render non exist bundles then create it in condition that i need it...

Answer (score 0):

You can load multiple javascript files (.js) in bundleConfig by including all .js file in single include() statement

```
bundles.add(
            new ScriptBundle(~/bundles/files).include(
            "file1.js",
            "file2.js",
            "file3.js));
```

OR

```
ScriptBundle scriptBndl = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap");    

//use Include() method to add all the script files with their paths 
scriptBndl.Include(
                   "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                   "~/Scripts/respond.js"
                  );


//Add the bundle into BundleCollection
bundles.Add(scriptBndl);
```